# Why does tomcat includes *.jspf fragments as static text while jetty processes them dynamically?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlet-container, jsp-fragments

I was developing my toy project using jetty maven plugin and executing goal `jetty:run`. Now i decided to check how it works on tomcat.

I have two jspf fragments: `header.jspf` and `footer.jspf` inside of `WEB-INF/jspf/` containing common code for all of my jsp pages. I include fragments like this:

```
<jsp:include page="WEB-INF/jspf/header.jspf" flush="true">
    <jsp:param name="pageTitle" value="Customer registration"/>
</jsp:include>
```

Jetty processed them like dynamic fragments, while tomcat processed them as static text, that's why i can see:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

in the beginning of web page in my browser. The issue with tomcat was solved easily by renaming: *.jspf into *.jsp. The question is: why different servlet containers act differently? I performed tests on tomcat 8/9 and jetty 9.3.7.

Answer (score 2):

Add a new file extension to mywebapp/WEB-INF/web.xml file. Why do Tomcat does not do this default I don't know. Defaults are in conf/web.xml file you could edit it as well. Another servlet engine may use different servlet name so this is Tomcat only solution.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: It's not a solution, if your servlet use a main jsp file which include a jsp fragment this solution failed